# Error processing package libjpeg-turbo8:amd64

Tags: apt, package-management

I'm trying a simple

```
sudo apt install php7.0-intl
```

And it returns this error:

```
...
dpkg: error processing package libjpeg-turbo8:amd64 (--configure):
 package libjpeg-turbo8:amd64 is not ready for configuration
 cannot configure (current status 'half-installed')
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libjpeg-turbo8:amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Then I ran:

```
sudo apt-get remove libjpeg-turbo8
```

And I got this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nginx : Depends: nginx-core (>= 1.10.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.2) but it is not going to be installed or
                  nginx-full (>= 1.10.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.2) but it is not going to be installed or
                  nginx-light (>= 1.10.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.2) but it is not going to be installed or
                  nginx-extras (>= 1.10.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.2) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: nginx-core (< 1.10.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.2.1~) but it is not going to be installed or
                  nginx-full (< 1.10.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.2.1~) but it is not going to be installed or
                  nginx-light (< 1.10.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.2.1~) but it is not going to be installed or
                  nginx-extras (< 1.10.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.2.1~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Comment: What happens when you do `sudo apt-get install --reinstall libjpeg-turbo8:amd64` ?

Comment: Are you using 16.04?